# Diagnosing Solar Inverter

Tags: solar-panels, solar

The goal is to correctly diagnose from the device's fault codes and determine corrective action.

A [SB6000U Sunny Boy inverter](http://www.solarhome.org/browseproducts/Sunny-Boy-SB6000U-(240v)-Inverter-With-LCD-Display.HTML) returns energy into the electric grid: reducing the electric bill significantly. The system has stopped returning into the grid.

Photos of the inverter error messages were snapped:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

From the [animation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qohQD51F5bM): I think normal operations is represented in this diagram:

[image]

## Is the inverter error messages represented with the following diagram:

[image]

Fuse blown:

[image]

Any tips for identifying exactly where the ground fault is introduced is appreciated.

Comment: The obvious question in my mind is did you check the GFDI fuse?

Comment: @jwh20 -- they know the fuse is blown, they're trying to figure out where the ground fault that blew the fuse is so they can do something smarter than throwing fuses at the problem :P

Comment: I'm not seeing that information in the question anywhere.  I believe you are reading more into this than is stated.  I'd try replacing the fuse and see if the problem persists.  Perhaps it was a transient, possibly caused by lightning that blew it.

Comment: @jwh20  If it were a transient, then searching for a "blue" short would be fruitless.  Is there any inspection procedure that would confirm a transient?  (other than throwing a good fuse at the system?)

Comment: Disconnecting both DC lines from the inverter and doing an insulation resistance test to ground would be the best option.

Comment: And you'll want to do that **at night**. 305 volts DC is *much, much, much more dangerous than you could possibly guess*.  At about 60 volts, DC power turns from Dr. Jekyll to Mr. Hyde.  A contactor rated for 2000 volts AC is only rated for 300 volts DC...  **DC will kill you**. AC arcs snuff out because they go to zero frequently.  If a DC arc starts, it can't be bargained with, it can't be reasoned with, it doesn't feel pity, or remorse, or fear! And it absolutely will not stop, ever, until you pull the trolley pole down. And you don't have a trolley pole!

Comment: This is twice your voltage https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThIbMnE71HU

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I had a dc arc welder... the arc does stop once the arc exceeds a given length - but it would put down a 6mm or 7mm rod effortlessly and leave an excellent finish.

Comment: @SolarMike What was your voltage, though?  Like I say, as DC gets above a certain voltage, it goes from Dr. Jekyll to Mr. Hyde.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Well, I remember that it zapped my ear as I was changing rods while under the car once - one of those errors you learn from..., but 80-100V open circuit from memory.